# In C++, How to read one file with multiple threads?

Tags: c++, python, multithreading, readfile

I am reading a .csv file from local hard drive using VS2012 in Windows 7, 64-bits, 8 core.

The file that I am reading has 50,000+ lines and each line has 200+ attributes, so read the data and feed them to corresponding variables is very time consuming. Therefore, I am wondering if I can speed it up with multithreads, that each thread reads a part of the file.

I've googled about it, and found someone said that, since the hard drive is not multithreading, using multiple threads to do so will acctually *slow it down*. **Is this true?**

If it is possible to read a file with multiple threads, can anyone give me **an example that I can learn from?**

Also, is it possible to **explicitly assign a thread or task to a CPU core?**

And a final question: I've read the same file with Python, and it has been finished with in few seconds. **May I know why Python read faster than C++?**

Comment: Generally speaking multi-threaded reading from a file will indeed slow things down.  The program may be multi-threaded, but consider the disk controller and the read/write heads ...  It's possible to construct exceptions to this rule, eg parallel file systems (you'd know if you had one), computations which do a lot of processing between reading chunks of a file, some other cases.

Comment: You could have one thread reading the file, then passing chunks to multiple parser threads. Then ideally you have a concurrent collection for holding the data, so worker threads can efficiently insert parsing results there quickly (assuming you need to have all data in one data structure in memory).

Comment: Unless processing the data once it has been read is very computationally expensive, reading a file using multiple threads won't help. Without seeing how you've implemented file reading in Python and C++ it would be difficult to know why you are seeing worse performance in C++. I'd guess you're using the C++ APIs incorrectly or poorly.

Comment: @Kylos The Python code is not mine, but I know that the original coder used csv.py to parse the csv file (I don't know much about python, I guess csv.py is a package or precompiled library). On the other hand, I code in C++ with STL, and the operations are explicitly excuted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading a file requires making a syscall in any language or OS, which means making a call to the underlying operating system, and waiting for it to put the contents of the file into memory for you (assuming you pass the OS's security checks and all that).  Multi-threading the file read would indeed slow you down since you'd be making more syscalls which pops you out of program execution and hands control over to the operating system.

As such, the best suggestion is the hyde's - perhaps split out the parsing of the file to multiple threads if need be.  If you're able to parse a file that large in a matter of a few seconds though, I'd say it's not really worth it.  For example, if you're running a graphical application, you definitely want to keep a separate thread for file loading so you don't freeze your UI.

On the matter of speed, I'd guess there's two primary issues.  Firstly, I suspect python reads it's files through a memory buffer by default, which would speed execution.  If you can buffer your file reads (so you can make fewer syscalls), you might see some performance gains.  The other issue would be which data structures you're using in Python and C++ to load/parse the data.  Without knowing your code, I can't suggest anything specific, but taking a little time to research/think about the different data structures applicable to your program might be useful.  Keep in mind Python's and C++'s data structures have very different performance profiles, so one that works well in Python may be a much worse choice in C++.

**Edit:** A simple sample of using file buffering in C++ STL from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/

```
 // read a file into buffer - sgetn() example
 #include <iostream>     // std::cout, std::streambuf, std::streamsize
 #include <fstream>      // std::ifstream

 int main () {
   char* contents;
   std::ifstream istr ("test.txt");

   if (istr) {
     std::streambuf * pbuf = istr.rdbuf();
     std::streamsize size = pbuf->pubseekoff(0,istr.end);
     pbuf->pubseekoff(0,istr.beg);       // rewind
     contents = new char [size];
     pbuf->sgetn (contents,size);
     istr.close();
     std::cout.write (contents,size);
   }
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Hi, Max. Thank you very much fo your answer. It is really instructive. Could you give me a simple example that show me how to set a reading buffer? Does it have to down to the hardware level? Many thanks again.

Comment: Assuming you're using the C++ STL, you can take a look at the documentation for std::filebuf here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/filebuf/

Comment: This method of seeking forth and back is precisely the reason people complain Microsoft's `bcp` does not work with anything but plain files, as a side note. You may like to use `std::vector<>` instead of plain `char*` array, there is no good reason here to use the latter.